# Eliminar duplicados error mysql una tabla

Tags: mysql

Deseo eliminar los nombres y apellidos duplicados en una tabla para cierto evento, en la consulta todo perfecto, pero cuando cambio el select por delete me sale un error

CONSULTA (FUNCIONANDO PERFECTAMENTE):

```
   WITH C AS
     (
      SELECT id,nombre,apellido,evento_id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                        nombre,apellido
                        ORDER BY id) AS DUPLICADO
      FROM usuario_evento
     )
     SELECT * FROM C 
     WHERE DUPLICADO > 1  
     AND evento_id = 10
```

al eliminar (AQUI ESTÁ EL ERROR)

```
 WITH C AS
 (
  SELECT id,nombre,apellido,evento_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                    nombre,apellido
                    ORDER BY id) AS DUPLICADO
  FROM usuario_evento
 )
 DELETE FROM C 
 WHERE DUPLICADO > 1  
 AND evento_id = 10
```

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete FROM C
WHERE DUPLICADO > 1
and evento_id = 10' at line 9

tengo instalado el servidor de mysql, supongo que está en la ultima version. No uso xampp ni nada por el estilo.

Comment: delete que???? falta especificar , no obstante puede que tu query regrese mas de una fila....

Comment: Tu mensaje de error no coincide con la consulta que estás mostrando.

Comment: ya edité y modifiqué lo ultimo, me di cuenta que pegué el que no era

Comment: bryro, lo que intento de decir en la consulta, es que me elimine todo que el numero de duplicado sea mayor a 1 y pertenezca a x evento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intentalo asi

join:

```
DELETE ue1 FROM usuario_evento ue1
INNER JOIN usuario_evento ue2 
WHERE
    ue1.id > ue2.id AND 
    ue1.nombre = ue2.nombre AND
    ue1.apellido= ue2.apellido AND
    ue1.evento_id = 10;
```

partiton:

```
DELETE FROM usuario_evento
WHERE 
    id IN (
    SELECT 
        id 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY nombre,apellido
                ORDER BY id) AS DUPLICADO
        FROM 
            contacts
        
    ) t
    WHERE DUPLICADO > 1 and evento_id  = 10
);
```

Comment: Oyeeeeeee muchisimas gracias, me sirvió bastante la consulta de partiton. Era algo tan sencillo y yo complicandome